# Общий ли корень у слов "начало" и "означать"?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Подумалось, а слова "начало" и "означать" - однокоренные? И, если да, то что означает их общий корень?

Answer (score 3):

Слово **НАЧАЛО** происходит от глаг. *nacęti «начать». Сущ.* načędlo «начало» образовано  с пом. предметного суф. -dl-o (как дело), впоследствии сочетание (dl упростилось в 1, а носовой звук [ę] у вост. славян изменился в ['а], отсюда соврем. **начало** «исходная точка, противоположное концу». Ср. ст.-сл. начѦло — тожд., в котором носовой звук отражен в букве Ѧ.  Праслав. * načęti развилось из *nаčenti «начать» после изменения **en** в конце слога в носовой гласн. **ę**. Глаг.* nаčenti образован с прист. nа- от *čenti — тожд., производного от корня* čen-, из *ken- (изменение перед е звука к в č). Корень * ken - является звуков. разновидностью корпя * kon - «начало» (чередов. о//e). См. конец.

Злово **ОЗНАЧАТЬ** происходит от глагола *значити*, который, в свою очередь, происходит от слова *знак* и, далее, от слова *знать*. Праслав. *znati «знать», «отличить, заметить» представляет собой застывшую форму дат. падежа сущ.* znatь «знать», «то, что познано, порождено» (ср. соврем. сущ. *знать* «знатные люди», диал. также «знакомые, кого знаем»). Праслав. *znatь образовано с суф. -t-ь (как честь) от и.-е.* ĝen- «знать», вероятно, связанного с * ĝen «рождать», рождаться» > «быть в родстве» > «знать». 
Ср. греч. genos «род», gnōtos «известный, узнанный», gnōmōn «знаток, судья» и «указатель», gnosis «познание», diagnosis, давшее медиц. термин 
*диагноз* «распознавание», «определение болезни», лат. gnarus «знающий». 
На слав, почве ĝ > z > з перед е. 
От глаг. *знати* в древности образовано с пом. суф. -ък-ъ (как *звук*) сущ. знакъ > знак «черта, рубец и т. п.», т. е. «помета о том, что данный предмет уже видели и отличили его от других». Сущ. *знакъ* послужило основой для образования глаг. *значити* (чередов. к//ч) — вначале «ставить знак», «метить» (как укр. значити «делать метки»), затем переосмысленного в «означать», «иметь содержание», «быть важным» и т. п. С соврем. содержанием глаг. *значить* отмечается в рус. словарях с XVIII в. От него происходит сущ. *значение* «смысл, содержание», отмечаемое в словарях с XVIII в.

Таким образом, слова НАЧАЛО и ОЗНАЧАТЬ не являются однокоренными как в современном языке, так и в диахронии, то есть этимологически. Это всего лишь созвучие.